# CMSensorRecorder for gyroscope data

Tags: ios, core-motion

iOS lets you specify that accelerometer data should be recorded, and then allows you access to the recordings at a later date:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmsensorrecorder

But, is there the equivalent for the gyroscope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but of course *you* can watch the gyroscope at any time. The reason is that the gyroscope, unlike the core motion sensor, is very battery-heavy and doesn't even run unless some app asks it to.